# Hide "Grand Total (Excl.Tax)" and "Tax" in order email

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, tax, pdf

I would ask if there's a way to hide the "Grand Total (Excl.Tax)" and "Tax" sections from the order transactional email.

[image]

I've Magento CE 1.9.0.1.

Has someone ever done it?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to Magento Admin, then:

> System -> Configuration -> SALES (left panel) -> Tax -> Orders,
>   Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings -> Include Tax In Grand Total
>   -> **Choose 'No'**

The order email will only display **'Grand Total'**.

Tested in Magento Community V 1.8.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Shopping Cart Display Settings in the admin:

`System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings`

- Display Prices
- Display Subtotal
- Display Shipping Amount
- Include Tax In Grand Total
- Display Full Tax Summary
- Display Zero Tax Subtotal

Changing the settings here and reviewing the shopping cart will surely help you arrive at a configuration that you are looking for.